# Changing my login e-mail in StackExchange

Tags: support, login, stack-exchange-openid

I am not trying to change my e-mail in the various StackExchange profiles I have.

Rather, when I log into a StackExchange site, and I log in using the StackExchange OpenID, I use my e-mail.  I want to change that e-mail.  Is it possible?

When I get to my StackExchange profile and I click on the "Logins" link, I get an option to add more logins, but not to edit the one I already have there.

Comment: This should be on [Meta Stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I don't mind moving it, if you tell me how.

Comment: Just add another login, then remove your original one.

Comment: @Qantas 94 Heavy: That can be done?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: You are right.  The link you provided answers my question precisely -- though the answer I am looking for is not the first one in the list.  How does one go about un-asking a question?

Comment: Don't worry about it.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work.  When I try to add another SE OpenID, I get taken to the login screen, and when I press the SE OpenID button to add another one of these IDs, I am automatically logged in with my current SE OpenID and not given a change to add another one.

Comment: ALSO, the link doesn't provide the answer at all.  I added a yahoo ID as a new login.  But I still see no links whatsoever that allow me to delete logins.  Only adding logins seems to be allowed.  I tried both in Firefox and in Internet Explorer.  I cannot delete logins.

Comment: (Full disclosure: the add-another-SE-OpenID duplicate is my self-answered question.)

Comment: @michaelb958 yes it will be deleted unless edited.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was always under the impression that the word "possible" was also required.

Comment: @michaelb958 hmm... might be, I think that it look only for the link. Let's see!

Comment: Weird, I see a "remove" button when I click "my logins" on my profile.

Comment: @michaelb958 looks like I was right. :-)